# Posible incompatibilidad de plugins cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic3, notification

He actualizado los plugins de cordova y las plataformas de ionic 3 en mi proyecto, y al hacerlo he perdido las notificaciones locales que estaba usando para Android (version 8.0.0) e iOS 11. Sin embargo, puedo ver las notificaciones en el navegador. Esto ocurrió  al actualizar cordova-ios  a la versión 5.0.1 , pero a necesito para instalar mi proyecto en dispositivos actualizados. Estoy usando el plugin via Ionic Native wrapper.

Estos son los plugins de mi packages.json:

```
"plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": {},
      "cordova-plugin-dialogs": {}
    }
```

Con las siguientes versiones:

```
    cordova-android-support-gradle-release 3.0.1 
    cordova-plugin-actionsheet 2.3.3
    cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9
    cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3
    cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2
    cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.0.0
    cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3
    cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1
    cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.3
    cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2
    cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4
    uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator 4.2.0

En mi package.json tengo estas dependencias:

 "dependencies": {
   ...
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.6.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "9.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.1",
    "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "1.2.1",
    "cordova": "9.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "8.0.0",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "3.0.1",
    "cordova-browser": "6.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "5.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "4.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notifications": "1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.4",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    ...
  },
```

¿Podría haber algún tipo de incompatibilidad? no tengo muy claro si el paquete "cordova-plugin-local-notifications": "1.0.0", es el más apropiado para utilizar con las notificaciones de Ionic.

Gracias de antemano.